# How to install uCos on arm9 [ mini2440 ]

Tags: embedded, arm, rtos, arm9, ucos

I'm very new to embedded programming, and my first project is installing uCos on [mini2440](http://www.friendlyarm.net/products/mini2440) [arm9] . Are there any tutorials for beginner like me to install uCos on arm9 ?

Thanks first :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Micro-C/OS is not a stand-alone OS like say Linux, it is a Real-time kernel, and as such you do not "install" it on a board separate to your application, instead you *link* it as a library to your application, then install the monolithic application image on your board.

There are many ways you could do that, it is board and/or chip specific, and also depends on what device programming tools you have at your disposal.  ARM9 describes only the core architecture, not the processor.  Processors and boards using and ARM9 device may have their own bootstrapping options, either on-chip or provided on-board as a bootloader, some may have no such pre-loaded bootstrap support and you will need to provide appropriate start-up code at the reset address, as well as having the necessary tools to program the external memory.

The documentation for your board indicates that it is pre-loaded with a bootloader called [Supervivi](http://code.google.com/p/friendlyarm/wiki/Supervivi). The documentation appears to only cover Linux and WinCE installations, but I imagine it can be used for downloading and running other images as well.